How to return specific fields only in POSTMAN response?
I am accessing third party API (not a public API) where I want to fetch specific fields only. How to do that?
Let's say I have an API {{URL}}/api/records/:recordId which returns the following:
{
  "id": 707348,
  "created-at": "2024-04-08T14:28:23-07:00",
  "updated-at": "2024-04-08T14:28:24-07:00",
  "currency": {
    "code": "USD"
  },
  "approvals": [
    {
      "id": 5612517,
      "created-at": "2024-04-08T14:28:24-07:00",
      "updated-at": "2024-04-08T14:28:46-07:00",
      "position": 1,
      "approval-chain-id": 729,
      "status": "approved"
    },
    {
      "id": 5612518,
      "created-at": "2024-04-08T14:28:42-07:00",
      "updated-at": "2024-04-08T14:28:42-07:00",
      "position": 2,
      "approval-chain-id": null,
      "status": "pending_approval"
    }
  ]
}

Here, if I add query params like this, {{URL}}/api/records/:recordId?fields=["id", "created-at"] then I get desired result:
{
    "id": 707348,
    "created-at": "2024-04-08T14:28:23-07:00"
}

How can I just retrieve currency (an object) or some value within this object? Same thing with approvals which is an array.
If I do {{coupa_url}}/api/invoices/:invoiceId?fields=["currency"] then I just get an empty array with 200 response.

No one here is going to know that.  It will be down to the third party API specification whether it supports that type of query or not.

I was able to use fields as shown below to get desired results.
i.e.,
{{URL}}/api/records/:recordId?fields=["id", "created-at",{"currency":{}}] returns below.
{
  "id": 707348,
  "created-at": "2024-04-08T14:28:23-07:00",
  "currency": {
    "code": "USD"
  }
}

{{URL}}/api/records/:recordId?fields=["id", "created-at",{"approvals":{}}] returns below.
{
  "id": 707348,
  "created-at": "2024-04-08T14:28:23-07:00",
  "approvals": [
    {
      "id": 5612517,
      "created-at": "2024-04-08T14:28:24-07:00",
      "updated-at": "2024-04-08T14:28:46-07:00",
      "position": 1,
      "approval-chain-id": 729,
      "status": "approved"
    },
    {
      "id": 5612518,
      "created-at": "2024-04-08T14:28:42-07:00",
      "updated-at": "2024-04-08T14:28:42-07:00",
      "position": 2,
      "approval-chain-id": null,
      "status": "pending_approval"
    }
  ]
}


